# Is there a way to separate query results in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I got a simple query which return a results from an `OrderLine` table. Is there a way to visually separate the query results to make it easier to read, like in the image shown here?

```
SELECT [OrderNo], [LineNo] 
FROM [OrderLine]
```

Results:

[image: Query Results]

Comment: Queries are not intended for display... use a front end of some sort, Excel or otherwise, to make your data pretty.

Comment: I don't need a front end or a UI, It's just for me, when I'm developing.

Comment: No, there is no easy and natural way to do it. Only ugly hacks

Comment: @juergend Can you share some of these ugly hacks with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table if exists #OrderLine;

select object_id as OrderNo, abs(checksum(newid())) as [LineNo]
into #OrderLine
from sys.columns;

-- ... results to text (ctrl+T)?
select OrderNo, [LineNo], 
case when lead(OrderNo, 1) over(partition by OrderNo order by OrderNo) = OrderNo then '' else replicate('-', 11) + char(10) end
from #OrderLine;

--inject NULL
select case when [LineNo] is null and flag=2 then null else TheOrderNo end as OrderNo, [LineNo]
from
(
    select OrderNo AS TheOrderNo, [LineNo], 1 as flag
    from #OrderLine
    union all
    select distinct OrderNo, NULL, 2
    from #OrderLine
) as src
order by TheOrderNo, flag;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could execute multiple queries like so:

```
DECLARE @i int = 1
DECLARE @OrderNo
DECLARE @OrderNos TABLE (
    Idx smallint Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1)
    , OrderNo int
)

INSERT @OrderNos
SELECT distinct [OrderNo] FROM [OrderLine]

WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM @employee_table))
BEGIN

    SET @OrderNo = (SELECT [OrderNo] FROM [OrderNos] WHERE [Idx] = @i)

    SELECT [OrderNo], [LineNo] 
    FROM [OrderLine]
    WHERE [OrderNo] = @OrderNo

    SET @i = @i + 1

END
```

Comment: that works thanks, don't forget to add `set @i = @i + 1;` before END

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly do that. Perhaps add a new column that is either null or has a value in it so that it is alternating.
Something like this:

```
select ..., case when rank() over (order by OrderNO) % 2 then 'XXX' else null end 
from....
```

The % 2 is a 'modulo' operator...